# iOS get Game Center email, first name and last name in code

Tags: email, game-center

I am working in a unity project I need to get email address, first name and last name of authenticated local player.

Can we get it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Social interface.

You authenticate with

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(callback);
```

Then you can access all the user info using

```
Social.localUser
```

See the example from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social-localUser.html below

```
using UnityEngine;
class c {
    void foo() {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate (success => {
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log ("Authentication successful");
            string userInfo = "Username: " + Social.localUser.userName + 
                "\nUser ID: " + Social.localUser.id + 
                "\nIsUnderage: " + Social.localUser.underage;
            Debug.Log (userInfo);
        }
        else
            Debug.Log ("Authentication failed");
    });
  }
}
```

If the info about the player you need is not available but should be (through the native gamecenter API), then you might have to download another platform plugin for unity to use with the Social interface (as you would have to do for Android)

Comment: I just checked apple game kit documentation it does not allow to give email, first name and last name  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/playerID

Comment: According to your link, you can use 
`alias` (a string chosen by the player to identify themself to other players) and `displayName` (a string to display for the player). I assumed that the second one is name - firstname, in a specific format. I didn't find anything about email on IOS (I know it is available on android) so you might be right about it.